# How to repeat a string until the length of another string, including spaces?

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

For example,

```
string1 = "The earth is dying"`
string2:"trees"
```

I want a new string to be: `tre estre es trees`

I was thinking to split the first string into a list and iterate through, but I having trouble getting a second for loop that would iterate through the second string and add it to the first one until the right length is reached? Also, I would have some type of if statement that would check for spaces and add them into the final list. And then possibly join the final list?

```
final_string = ''
string1_list = list(string1)
for i in range(string1_list):
    if string1_list[i] != " " #aka has a letter there
        for j in range(...) # how do I get a loop that would go through string2
        final_string += ... # and add into this string
```

Comment: Feel free to post your code attempts and we will surely be able to help you solve your problem. :) - Your ideas are a good start!

Answer (score 1):

```
string1 = "The earth is dying"
string2 = "trees" 
result = ""
index = 0
for character in string1:
    if character == " ":
        result += " "
    else:
        result += string2[index%len(string2)]
        index+=1
print(result)
```

Output:   `"tre estre es trees"`

Comment: If i were to iterate through result it would print result[i] as blocks of letters though, how can i do this so that if I print result[i] it would be like t,r,e, ,s, ... vs how it is now which is tres,estre?

Answer (score 1):

With [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) *magic*:

```
from itertools import cycle

s1 = "The earth is dying"
s2 = "trees"

gen = cycle(s2)
res = ''.join(c if c.isspace() else next(gen) for c in s1)
print(res)
```

The output:

```
tre estre es trees
```